# How to debug a C++ dll with VisualStudio+cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, cmake, dll

I'm trying to debug a dll with an external application not belonging to the solution.
I'm using VisualStudio+cmake
I've set up the launch.vs.json with something like:

```json
  {
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},1
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "mydll.dll",
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "mydll.dll",
      "program": "external_program.exe",
      "args": [ "path_to_input_file" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It doesn't work.
What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need symbols for that library to debug or the library must be built with debug symbols attached (i.e a debug dll).
After that you can 'attach to that process' which is loading the dll.
[how to attach to a process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLzil.png)

Comment: I have already copied the pdb files to the right location.
I don't want to attach to the process because before I could do that the process would have exited

Comment: With VS+Solution, in the debug configuration, you can change the path to the executable. It's very simple

I would like to do he same with VS+CMake

Answer (score 0):

I think the [VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND.html) and [VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS.html) properties do what you want.

Using MSVC, the following cmake project will build a mydll.dll library
that, when debugged, will run `C:/path/to/external_program C:/path/to/mydll.dll`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(mydll)

find_program(EXTERNAL_PROGRAM NAMES external_program)
if(NOT EXTERNAL_PROGRAM)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find external_program")
endif()

add_library(mydll SHARED source1.c)
set_target_properties(mydll
    PROPERTIES
        VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND "${EXTERNAL_PROGRAM}"
        VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND_ARGUMENTS "$<TARGET_FILE:mydll>"
)
```

To create a MSVC project, run the following command from the directory containing the above `CMakeLists.txt`.
This will configure the CMake project, and open Visual Studio.

```
cmake -S . -B build -DEXTERNAL_PROGRAM="C:/path/to/external_program.exe"
cmake --open build
```

Because `external_program.exe` is external code, you need to [enable debugging of external sources](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugging-external-sources-with-visual-studio/).
This can be done as follows:

```
- In the Tools -> Options -> Debugging options
  - Disable Just My Code: This will allow the debugger to attempt to locate symbols for code outside your solution.
```

Comment: Thanks, but when the menu entry "Start Debugging" is still disabled